# How to detect coordinates of Ribbon bar in Win32 API

Tags: winapi, windows-ribbon-framework

I'm making an application in Win32 API that uses the modern Ribbon style UI. I've successfully tested an SampleRibbon program. The only problem I'm having is that, ***How to detect the X and Y coordinates of the Ribbon bar?*** When I draw a control at (0,0) it gets hidden behind the Ribbon bar. But I don't want it to be hidden behind the bar. Is there any function to get the coordinates of the Ribbon bar so that I can draw the control automatically below the Ribbon.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function you're looking for is [`IUIRibbon::GetHeight`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd742708(v=vs.85).aspx).